# How to use command line Matlab from .NET without linking?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, process, filesystemwatcher

I finally discovered a way to use command line Matlab from .NET without linking:

1. Write variables from .NET to a MAT file using David A. Zier's "csmatio" dll.
2. Read the file from Matlab, process it and save the results to a MAT file:

   ```
   var process = new Process()
   {
       StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
       {
           FileName = MatlabExecutableFileName,
           Arguments = "-nodisplay " + 
              "-nojvm " +
              " -r \"somecommands; " + 
              "save FILENAME OUTPUTVARIABLES; " +
              "exit;\""
       }
   };
   process.Start();
   ```
3. **The worst part:** Wait until the process finishes.

   The naive approach:

   ```
   process.WaitForExit();
   ```

   Doesn't work because matlab spawns the main application in a new thread

   Watching for the output file for changes is tricky:

   ```
   new FileSystemWatcher(MatlabPath, fileName)
       .WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.All)
   ```

   Was not working because of a bug on this class.

   The currently working code is longer:

   ```
   using (var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(MatlabPath, fileName))
   {
       var wait = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
       watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
       watcher.Changed += delegate(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
       {
          wait.Set();
       };
       foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 2))
       {
           if (!wait.WaitOne(MillissecondsTimeout))
           {
               throw new TimeoutException();
           }
       }
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
   ```

   But I am concerned about the last line of code. The code block above was written with the intent of avoiding it, but I don't know what else to do. This amount of time will be too much on some computers and too little on others.

**SOLUTION**

```
var previousProcesses = Process
    .GetProcessesByName("Matlab")
    .Select(a => a.Id)
    .ToArray();
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
var currentProcess = Process
    .GetProcessesByName("Matlab")
    .Where(a => !previousProcesses.Contains(a.Id))
    .First();
currentProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much better option is the `-wait` flag for matlab. It tells the matlab starter to terminate together with the main matlab process.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I completely understand the question (you're essentially trying to detect when the matlab process finishes right?), but couldn't you find matlab's main application process & wait for it to exit? i.e. something like this:

```
process.WaitForExit();  //only waits for the launcher process to finish
//but now matlab should be running in a new process...
var matlabProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("whatever process is called");
//assuming only one matlab instance running...
//you'd probably want to write some defensive code here...
matlabProcess[0].WaitForExit();
```

Seems like that would be simpler than trying to watch it change files & guess when its finished...

Answer (score 0):

How about determining the actual process for the separate thread and calling `WaitForExit` on it?  Maybe use the command line program `tasklist` to get the PID's of all MATLAB processes and filter out the PID of the one you have.

Alternatively, there might be a .NET structure (probably related to `process`) which could return a child thread of `process` and wait for it.

Unfortunately, I don't know details, but it's worth a try searching that avenue.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly changed the Solution so it worked for me

```
var previousProcesses = Process
   .GetProcessesByName("Matlab")
   .Select(a => a.Id)
   .ToArray();
var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
var newProcessRunning = Process
   .GetProcessesByName("Matlab")
   .Where(a => !previousProcesses.Contains(a.Id));
if (newProcessRunning.Count() != 0)
   newProcessRunning.First().WaitForExit();
```